# How to properly upload file to document library using CSOM?

Tags: javascript, soap, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-jsom

I'm trying to upload a file to a document library using the FileReader object, but failing to do so, since the files are uploaded in the wrong encoding.

This is code

```
$("#file").kendoUpload({
    async: {
        saveUrl: "save",
        autoUpload: true
    },
    upload: function (e) {
        $.each(e.files, function () {
            var file = this.rawFile;
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                var data = reader.result;
                var soapEnv =
                    "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='ht
                    <soap:Body>\
                        <CopyIntoItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'>\
                            <SourceUrl>" + file.name + "</SourceUrl>\
                                <DestinationUrls>\
                                    <string>"+GetHostname() + folder + "/" + file.name + "</string>\
                                </DestinationUrls>\
                                <Fields>\
                                      <FieldInformation Type='Text' DisplayName='Title' InternalName='Title' Value='"+ file.name + "'  />\
                                </Fields>\
                            <Stream>" +window.btoa(data) + "</Stream>\
                        </CopyIntoItems>\
                    </soap:Body>\
                </soap:Envelope>";
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/documents/_vti_bin/copy.asmx",
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/CopyIntoItems"); },
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    data: soapEnv,
                    contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
                }).then(function (data, status) {
                    var itemUrl = xmlToJSON(data).Envelope.Body.CopyIntoItemsResponse.Results.CopyResult._DestinationUrl;                           
                    return documentsUtilities.checkIn(itemUrl);
                })
                .then(function(res){
                    //notifiy user and automatically reload the grid
                });
            };
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    }
```

The problem im facing is located in the soap - string itself.

Passing around that data as `<Stream>" +window.btoa(data) + "</Stream>` results in the file being uploaded with its content as base64 encoded. Images are black and text files are unreadable.

Passing the data object itself with `<Stream>" + data + "</Stream>\` results in a bad request.

What is the correct way to upload a file into document library on SharePoint 2010 using the FileReader API?

Answer (score 0):

The FileReader API result is a base64 encoded string with a bit of overhead, that specifies the actual file type. In case of a pdf file that would look like this:

```
data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjQKJdP0zOEKMSAwIG9iago8PAovQ3JlYXRpb25EYXRlKEQ6MjAxNzA5MjcxNTMz....
```

Removing the bit at the beginning including the comma after base64 is all that it takes to make SharePoint happy:

```
<Stream>" + data.replace(/^.*base64,/, '') + "</Stream>\
```

I've tested this now on jpg, png, xlsx, docx, pdf and js files. Works like a charm.